# 401 returned from API gateway using Cognito authorizer - no matter what is passed in

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, authorization, aws-amplify

I've got users able to log in, and log out, sign up, password reset - all using  AWS amplify in my React.js code.

After they are signed in, I want to fetch my API gateway, that is using Authorization: UserCognito, **then going to a lambda function where I want to be able to pull the data passed into my API and return their information from the dynamoDB with their profile info (such as name, picture, email).**

When I fetch the API, I get `{"message":"Unauthorized"}`

I'm calling the api like this:

```
     getProfileInfo(user.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken).then(user => {
                console.log(user);
              });
```

and have even tried this:

`````
```

let token = await Auth.currentCredentials();
      console.log(token);
      const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",

          Authorization: token.sessionToken
        }
      };

      let res = GetProfileInfo(token.sessionToken);
      API.post("XXURL", "", options);

````
`````

With getProfileInfo looking like:

```
      const getProfileInfo = async user => {
      let url = XXXXXXXX
      console.log(user);
      const data = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          Authorization: user
        },
        mode: "cors"
      })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          return data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          return error;
        });
      return data;
```

So - how do I pass in my user's info from AWS-amplify, into my API, **on the react front end side** - so it can authorize them, then run my lambda function where I take their user information and look up their profile in my DynamoDB?

My API gateway, has the token assigned to the value of `Authorization` when setting up my authorizer.

Also, I have template mappings set up for my API that look like this:

````
```
    {
    "context" : {
        "sub" : "$context.authorizer.claims.sub",
        "email" : "$context.authorizer.claims.email"
    }
    }
```
````

But still nothing but Unauthorized is returned. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you actually have a valid JWT  in `user` in your `getProfileInfo()` then try to use

```
headers: {
  ...
  Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user    
}
```

maybe you also want to verify that you have a valid token on a site like [jwt.io](https://jwt.io)

Comment: Adding both "Bearer" and "JWT" to the authorization header did not work either. JWT.io says my JWT token is invalid. I'm getting it in two ways: ```user.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken``` and ```Auth.currentSession()``` Why does it say its invalid?? The user in logged in and its valid

Comment: we are actually doing it like this: `currentSession = await Auth.currentSession();` and then add `currentSession.getIdToken().getJwtToken()` to actually get the latest token. I guess that's what you did too. JWT.io should not be able to validate signature (unless you provide it) but do you @Zach actually get information out of the token or is it completly broken? - if you get information out of the token. try to check API gateway again and see if you use are using the same cognito user pool for client and in the gateway..

Comment: It worked. Providing the right token and with ```"Bearer " +``` was the key.  Thank you so much. This isn't documented anywhere..... They don't say using Bearer is required at all. So thank you so helpful

Comment: @Zach I think the right token is jwtToken from the Auth.currentSession(). I am getting 401, {message: "Your token has expired} occasionally.